# TOC numbering bug: "2. ;1.5. ; 1.6." in place of "2. ;2.1. ; 2.2."

Tags: microsoft-word

I have MS Word 2010. I edit a big document with a lot of Headings. But I experience ussues with numbering restarting.

I want my file to be structured this way:

```
1.
1.1.
1.2.
2.
2.1.
2.2.
3.
3.1.
3.2.
```

But it is structured this way:

```
1.
1.1.
1.2.
2.
1.3.
1.4.
3.
1.5.
1.6.
```

Please note that "Heading 2" texts are not restarted, they are just 1.x

Can you suggest me what to to fix this.

Comment: [Heading 2 numbering not resetting to follow preceding Heading 1.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/heading-2-numbering-not-resetting-to-follow/2736f8b3-6ea7-4b98-8411-b08e4b977c4a?auth=1)

Comment: You're welcome. Answer provided ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I experience issues with numbering restarting.

> You must set up the heading numbering as a multilevel list linked to the heading styles.
>
> **If you select the 1 Heading 1, 1.1 Heading 2, 1.1.1 Heading 3 list type in the Multilevel List gallery, the list levels will be linked to the styles automatically, will have the numbering you want, and will restart after higher levels.**
>
> For more on this, see [How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).
>
> Once the numbering is linked to the styles, you can modify the formatting of the styles any way you like (in the Modify Style dialog) except wrt numbering; any changes to the numbering or indents (left or hanging) must be made in the Define New Multilevel List dialog.

Source [Heading 2 numbering not resetting to follow preceding Heading 1.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/heading-2-numbering-not-resetting-to-follow/2736f8b3-6ea7-4b98-8411-b08e4b977c4a?auth=1)